# Ruby: Minitest, test-unit and instance variables

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, thread-safety

(Posted already at https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6876320, but crossposted here, because I did not receive a response so far).

A question about parallelizing tests in Minitest and/or Test::Unit (i.e. proper use of parallelize_me!):

Assume that I have some helper methods, which are needed by several tests.  From my understanding, I could NOT do something like this in such a method (simplified example):

```
def prep(m,n)
 @pid = m
 @state = n
end

def process
 if @stat > 5 && @pid != 0
   ...
 else
   ...
 end
end
```

I think I can't do this in Minitest and test-unit, because if I call prep and process from several of my test function, the tests can not be parallelized anymore - those test functions all set and read the same instance variable. Right?

Now, my question is, whether the following approach would be safe for parallelization: I make all of these mutable instance variables a hash, which I initialized in setup like this:

```
def setup
  @pid ||= {}
  @state ||= {}
end
```

My "helper methods" receive a key (for example, the name of the test
method) and use it to access the their "own" hash element:

```
def prep(key,m,n)
 @pid[key] = m
 @state[key] = n
end

def process
 if @stat[key] > 5 && @pid[key] != 0
   ...
 else
   ...
 end
end
```

It's a bit ugly, but: Is this a reliable approach? Is this way of accessing a hash thread-safe? How can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Minitest you can safely do, for example,

```
setup do
  @form = Form.new
end
```

without `@form` getting mixed up between parallel tests, so this approach should be safe too:

```
def setup
  @stat = m
  @pid = n
end
```

which means that your original approach should be safe as well.

================

**UPDATE**

consider the following gist with a piece of code that define 100 different tests accessing `@random` which is set in `setup` https://gist.github.com/bbozo/2a64e1f53d29747ca559

You will notice that the stuff set in `setup` isn't shared among tests, it is run before every test, basically every test is encapsulated so thread safety isn't an issue.

Comment: How can my original approach work? `setup` is called just right before any test case, and the instance variables (@stat ...) are shared between the test cases. If the cases run in parallel (in several threads), we have a race conditions on the instance variables.

Comment: It does indeed! However, the gist-code you wrote, doesn't  actually prove the case. In most cases, the output is just a sequence of setup/test/setup/test/..., so even if the variable would be shared among tests, you would get the output. The two cases, where the output is setup/setup/test/test, could, maybe, an artefact of output buffering. I took the liberty to modify your code a bit, to rule out these cases, and the modified code really proves your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the hashes makes sense, and it *will work* to distinguish between the threads. The problem lies with the Global Interpreter Lock.

Unless your helper methods are IO-bound (make HTTP requests, socket requests, handle local files), you won't see a speed improvement because Ruby will pretty much (to simplify things) run your code sequentially over multiple threads, without a guaranteed run order.

Good luck!